# What does . mean in bash? (As in ". script.sh")

Tags: bash

I am used to running shell scripts with for example

```
source script.sh
```

I was surprised to learn recently that this also works

```
. script.sh
```

The single dot of course normally indicates the current directory so I am now confused. Can anyone explain this use of .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=descriptions-dot-run-shell-file-in-current-environment): ".(dot) runs a shell script in the current environment and then returns. Normally, the shell runs a command file in a child shell so that changes to the environment by such commands as cd, set, and trap are local to the command file. The . (dot) command circumvents this feature.

If there are slashes in the file name, . (dot) looks for the named file. If there are no slashes . (dot) searches for file in the directories specified in the PATH variable. This may surprise some people when they use dot to run a file in the working directory, but their search rules are not set up to look at the working directory. As a result, the shell does not find the shell file."

Answer (score 1):

`.` (dot) and `source` mean the same thing in the `bash` language.

In fact the (dot) form is the **standard** form according to the POSIX Shell Specification. The `source` form is a `bash` extension, but not a `bash` invention.  (The venerable Berkley C-shell (`csh`) used to use `source` rather than `.`.)

According to the POSIX Shell specification, `source` is a command name whose meaning is unspecified; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html